# Rails - how to make accessible one controller action for all pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action

I have in the footer **contact** form - in the app is the whole **contact** scaffold. How to make this form working? So far, I am trying to do it this way - in the footer I render the form action:

```
= render 'contact_messages/new'
```

and in the **ApplicationController** I set up the **before_filter**:

```
  before_filter :model_for_contact
  def model_for_contact_messages
    @contact_message = ContactMessage.new
  end
```

But when I open the app, I am getting this error message in browser:

```
private method `new' called for ContactMessage:Class
```

How to solve this thing?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT** - **contact_message.rb**

```
class ContactMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :email, :name, :subject
end
```

Comment: What is the code of `ContactMessage` class?

Comment: Added - just a basicaly generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search found me these:

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3716180#1048623

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388748/832759

So perhaps you also have a mailer class with the name `ContactMessage`?

Comment: I was going for the same thing, but I copied and pasted the wrong link

Answer (score -1):

I checked this question,

[Ruby Class#new - Why is `new` a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380648/ruby-classnew-why-is-new-a-private-method)

From the above link and a little bit of google I did,

I found that, [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html) link's ContactMessage class in the ActiveModel::Conversion, may have contradicted with your definition.

Comment: No `ContactMessage` in there is just an example code. And that is the only place this constant exist for the entire codebase https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=ContactMessage&ref=cmdform